# Examples of $C^*$-algebras in Noncommutative Geometry from A. Connes

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quotient-spaces, noncommutative-geometry

**Question**

I am working on $C^*$-algebras and I've been given Alain Connes's  book [Noncommutative Geometry](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf). I am having troubles with understanding the examples on pages 91-93 (86-88 in the printed book). Maybe the problem is, that I do not understand, how those algebras are constructed. Could somebody explain the second way of the construction (page 91 (85))? I am talking about the part starting:

2) The second is to consider the larger algebra $B \supset C(Y)$ of all $2 \times 2$ matrices:
$$
f =
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{aa} & f_{ab} \\
f_{ba} & f_{bb} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
...

I do not really understand, how to construct this matrix in general. For example - what is $f_{aa}, f_{ab},\ldots$? How are those constructed/represented e.g. in the example $2.\beta$ **The dual of the infinite dihedral group** (pages 92-93 (87-88))?

Many thanks.

**[Update 2]**

After two days of without activity I've asked the same question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/204645/72311). I might delete one of them later, do not want to *spam*.

**[Update 1]**

I would be glad to receive any tips or guesses. I am aware, that this is broad topic, I am not looking for precise and rigorous explanation (although that would be also appreciated).

Comment: Should I rephrase the question? Or ask more precisely? I understand this is not a _look and see_ Q/A, and it takes some time to read those few pages.

Comment: Just a quick comment (I would need to think a bit more about the dual of the infinite dihedral algebra): the $f_{aa}$ and so on are continuous functions on the space Y (i.e. elements of C(Y)), and the algebra B could be considered as the algebra of matrices with components functions on Y. Another way of looking at this is that B is the algebra of continuous functions from Y to matrices, with the multiplication being the pointwise multiplication of the matrices. I would suggest reading (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408416) for a clear exposition of these types of algebras (groupoid algebras).

Comment: Thanks, I think there are many more things, that I still do not understand. E.g., I see, how the $2\times 2$ matrices pop out (arbitrary $f \in C(Y)$ is given by values $f(a), f(b)$, therefore $C(Y) \cong (f(a) =\alpha, f(b) = \beta) \cong 2\times 2$ diagonal matrices), then considering all $2\times2$ matrices seems logical. But, how come the $2\times2$ matrices pop out also in 2.$\beta$, when in that case $2\neq \operatorname{card}Y = c$. Is it because we somehow generalize the previous concept for each $t \in [0,1]$? $f\in C(I_1 \cup I_2)$ is also determined by values for each point.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem now:the size of the matrices is not related to the size of the space on which the functions live, but on the "size" of the equivalence relation (i.e. how many points are identified with each other). I would say it is a bit disingenuous to name this a dual of the infinite dihedral group, I would just call this algebra the noncommutative quotient of closed line by an action of Z/2Z which is not proper (for example the inverse image of the compact set containing just one of the points at 1 will be non-compact). When I have time I will try to write up a proper answer.

Comment: Yes, I was definitely confused by this _coincidence_. Please [see](http://mathoverflow.net/a/204656/72311) before you write more (that answer helped a lot, however I don't  want to discourage you from writing your own, just to save you time, writing some thoughts :). It would be probably better to delete this question, and discuss this topic further on [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/204645/72311). And thanks for the paper, although some parts look too advanced for me yet.